# Rails doesn't serve assets with hash in their name in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have the following images in my assets folders:

```
/assets/bundles/riverstreet-12e3a07deb732425897f8aa7f76c6859.jpg
/assets/images/riverstreet.jpg
```

Both of these folders are added to the asset path of the app

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('assets', 'bundles')
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('assets', 'images')
```

And yet, when I try to access the one with the hash in its name, I get an error.

```
http://localhost:5000/assets/riverstreet.jpg // Looks good
http://localhost:5000/assets/riverstreet-12e3a07deb732425897f8aa7f76c6859.jpg // Errors out
```

This is the error

```
No route matches [GET] "/riverstreet-12e3a07deb732425897f8aa7f76c6859.jpg"
```

Comment: Is the `bundles` directory added to your rails assets configuration? A better way to test your theory would be to have the images in the same directory. Lastly, ensure you restart your server. See what that yields :)

Comment: `Rails.root.join('assets', 'bundles')` generates: `/project/assets/bundles` and you need to do `Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'bundles')` which genrates `/project/app/assets/bundles`.

Comment: I added the bundles at /project/assets/bundles. It's not under the traditional location of asset files for a Rails app.